# Converting sentences in a file to word tokens in a list

Tags: python, file, list-comprehension

I'm using python to convert the words in sentences in a text file to individual tokens in a list for the purpose of counting up word frequencies. I'm having trouble converting the different sentences into a single list. Here's what I do:

```
f = open('music.txt', 'r')
sent = [word.lower().split() for word in f]
```

That gives me the following list:

```
[['party', 'rock', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'house', 'tonight'],
 ['everybody', 'just', 'have', 'a', 'good', 'time'],...]
```

Since the sentences in the file were in separate lines, it returns this list of lists and defaultdict can't identify the individual tokens to count up.

It tried the following list comprehension  to isolate the tokens in the different lists and return them to a single list, but it returns an empty list instead:

```
sent2 = [[w for w in word] for word in sent]
```

Is there a way to do this using list comprehensions? Or perhaps another easier way?

Comment: @Sven Marnach's solution is a good one. A general solution to the problem of wanting to denest a nested list is the use of `itertools.chain()`. See http://ideone.com/g4YMu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a nested loop inside the list comprehension:

```
sent = [word for line in f for word in line.lower().split()]
```

There are some alternatives to this approach, for example using `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`, but I think the nested loop is much easier in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the entire file to memory,a s a single string, and apply `split`once tot hat string.
There is no need to read the file line by line in such a case.

Therefore your core can be as short as:

```
sent = open("music.txt").read().split()
```

(A few niceties like closing the file, checking for errors, turn the code a little larger, of course)

Since you want to be counting word frequencies, you can use the collections.Counter class for that:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
for word in open("music.txt").read().split():
    counter[word] += 1
```

Comment: You don't initialise `counter`.  And you don't need the loop -- `Counter(open("music.txt").read().split())` will be enough.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: ah..thanks, I did not recall how to initialise the counter in this way. On the other hand, doing it the way I did assumes that non-existing keys contain `0` - so this code works.

Comment: What I meant -- your code is lacking the line `counter = Counter()`.  I know this is a trivial remark, and I *did* upvote your answer. :)  (The second part of my previous comment was unrelated to the first part.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: eek - sorry for that. just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions can do the job but will accumulate everything in memory.  For large inputs this could be an unacceptable cost.  The below solution will not accumulate large amounts of data in memory, even for large files.  The final product is a dictionary of the form `{token: occurrences}`.

```
import itertools

def distinct_tokens(filename):
  tokendict = {}
  f = open(filename, 'r')
  tokens = itertools.imap(lambda L: iter(L.lower.split()), f)
  for tok in itertools.chain.from_iterable(tokens):
    if tok in tokendict:
      tokendict[tok] += 1
    else:
      tokendict[tok] = 1
  f.close()
  return tokendict
```

Comment: `iflatten()` already exists in the standard library.  It is called `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`.